# KendoWindow: how to set header height?

Tags: kendo-ui

KendoWindow doesn't have configuration options to set the window header height, and I cannot find a way to do that manipulating CSS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector is `k-window-titlebar` but you might have to use `important` for some of the attributes. Define the CSS style as

```
.k-window-titlebar {
    height: 60px !important;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 30pt !important;
    background: red !important;
}
```

A snippet...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var window = $("#window");
  window.kendoWindow({
    width: "450px",
    title: "About Alvar Aalto",
    pinned: true
  });
});
```

```css
.k-window-titlebar {
  height: 60px !important;
  color: white !important;
  font-size: 30pt !important;
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.flat.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.flat.mobile.min.css" />
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="window">
  <p>
    Alvar Aalto is one of the greatest names in modern architecture and design. Glassblowers at the iittala factory still meticulously handcraft the legendary vases that are variations on one theme, fluid organic shapes that let the end user decide the use. Interpretations of the shape in new colors and materials add to the growing Alvar Aalto Collection that remains true to his original design.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your css

```
.k-window-titlebar {
   height: 50px;
   line-height: 50px; 
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```